# Automatically remove oldest rows when the database table grows too large?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to set up the MS SQL-Server to delete the oldest rows from a table when it grows too large? If not, should I use some sort of trigger or should this be a timed event in the application side?

My situation is that I have just implemented a logging solution for a web application. It is a requirement to log a lot of information, so the database will grow too large in a year or so, and I have a feeling that there will be nobody to maintain the database. Looking for the best solution for this problem.

Comment: What's too large? Why is it bad if it's "too large?" What is the recovery model of the database? What's the data model look like? Should it delete rows from all tables or are there certain tables that it should delete from while leaving say a reference table be? How is the size and cleanup job going to run, do we have access to a scheduling program? What edition of SQL Server are we talking about?

Comment: Perhaps partitioning the data in a table per year (month?) is an option? That way there is no real need to remove the old data. The older tables simply won't be accessed if you query with a date filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to determine ahead of time what too large is, I would suggest that you define a business rule somewhere (stored procedure, configuration table, etc) that can be set to control how many days worth of logging to keep.

You can then schedule a job to run nightly through SQL Server that will delete all log records older than the specified criteria.

This way, you and your users will know exactly what to expect from the logging system (i.e. you will only have access to the log files for 30 days).

If you combine this with a regular backup strategy, then in the event that older records are needed, they could be retrieved from backups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resource governor to measure resource usage or define a job that checks database file sizes and then call an SP that will delete data from database tables.